# Configuring Certbot for my website: "Network is unreachable"

Tags: certificate, nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I am trying to add SSL certificate on my website, I use for this Cerbot from this [guide](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx). And when I am typing this command

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

I see this error:

```
root@vps685363:~# sudo certbot --nginx
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
An unexpected error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7efd3ad03c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7efd3ad03c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/acme/client.py", line 1101, in _send_request
    response = self.session.request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7efd3ad03c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Requesting acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: Network is unreachable
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

What must I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the problem specified - OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

This means that the Certbot agent is unable to connect to the letsencrypt server. You need to fix the connectivity on the server so it can work.